# jpeg format open error in GIMP

Tags: installation, gimp

i can't open any file type except PNG format in GIMP.
actually i know that wasn't install libjpeg or  libtiff.

how i can fix it?

i compile source first and than purge it and install from repository. but again i can't open jpeg file.

i added this repo in source.list

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/gnome3-team/gnome3/ubuntu oneiric main
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ricotz/testing/ubuntu oneiric main

deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/matthaeus123/mrw-gimp-svn/ubuntu precise main 
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/matthaeus123/mrw-gimp-svn/ubuntu precise main
```

Comment: how compile gimp? what is your distro?

Comment: ubuntu 12.04. according to readme